Graph $ \sin(x^3) $
Graph $ \sin(x^3) $
I want to find the roots.
I thought triple angle identity would lead to finding roots but I get a different graph.  So this function is much different.
Here is the graph I am looking at

Here is my mistake.  I was wondering if someone could get me back on the right track?
$\sin^3(x) =\frac34 \sin(x) - \frac14 \sin(3x)$


So $x^3=\pi n$, $x=...$

Don't overcomplicate matters with the triple angle identity. We know that
$$
\sin \theta = 0 \text{ whenever } \theta = k \pi \text{ for some integer } k
$$
Hence, if $\sin x^3 = 0$, then
$$
x^3 = k \pi \text{ for some integer } k
$$

Is there anyway I can find the period, $ \frac{2 \pi}{B} $   I am a little overwhelmed by it.  It doesn't follow the usually pattern that I have studied.

Just take a look at the graph; it is $2\pi$-periodic (so $B=1$). Handling it more "properly" is a bit complicated (link).
